# How do I send files in an email by using the Python email module?

Tags: python, file, email

I heared, that you can send files per email using the email module. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you've already created a multipart:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
```

Then you can add an image by doing:

```
filename = "..."
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    attachment = MIMEImage(f.read())
```

or you can add the string `"Hello World"` as a `test.txt` by doing:

```
filename = "test.txt"
attachment = MIMEText("Hello World")
```

For binary files or just in general, you can do:

```
filename = "..."
ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
maintype, subtype = ctype.split("/", 1)
attachment = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    attachment.set_payload(f.read())
encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
```

*Remember `from email import encoders`.*

At the end you add them to the email by doing:

```
attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=filename)
msg.attach(attachment)
```

One important thing to remember, is that all files must be added first. The message **must** come last in order to conform with [RFC 2046](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt), which dictates:

> Receiving user agents should pick and display the last format they are capable of displaying.

Comment: `MIMEImage` has some specific stuff related to images, take a look at `MIMEBase` in contrast. `MIMEImage` basically does that behind the scenes to put it simply.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html)

example from the site

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Here are the email package modules we'll need
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

COMMASPACE = ', '

# Create the container (outer) email message.
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Our family reunion'
# me == the sender's email address
# family = the list of all recipients' email addresses
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(family)
msg.preamble = 'Our family reunion'

# Assume we know that the image files are all in PNG format
for file in pngfiles:
    # Open the files in binary mode.  Let the MIMEImage class 
    automatically
    # guess the specific image type.
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
    img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    msg.attach(img)

# Send the email via our own SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, family, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Comment: Can I only open images or also other files using this?

Answer (score 0):

You should first know the basics and focus on learning to send a basic email.
first, we have built-in module in python 'email' so we use its class 'EmailMessage'

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
```

Let's assume you would be using gmail. To send mail you should first enable 'less secure apps' in mail settings, this step is required to be able to send emails from a python script or you get a connection denied error while trying to send email.
next, you should import libraries for sending message through SMTP

```
import smtplib, ssl
```

email only sends strings through smtp and thus for sending any attachment you must convert it to strings using mimetypes

```
import mimetypes
```

also you require os module for processing attachment

```
import os
```

To enter password of email service at time of running script and in hidden way use getpass module

```
import getpass
```

now, we can create an object for message

```
message=EmailMessage()
```

now you should keep in mind, email object is like a dictionary, so go accordingly

```
message['From']='sender address as string'
message['To']='recipient address as string'
message['Subject']='subject of email as string'
```

body is little different, if you have one line body it can be just a string otherwise for nice formatting use docstring

```
body="""Hello!
        World"""
message.set_content(body)
```

now let's prepare attachment, first we process its path

```
attachment_path='use absolute path if possible for better implementation'
attachment_filename=os.path.basename(attachment_path)
```

If MIME type and subtype is not known mimetypes module can be used as:

```
mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(attachment_path)
```

Since we get 'mime_type' as type of mime and subtype separated by '/' we separate them as:

```
mime_type, mime_subtype=mime_type.split('/', 1)
```

now we are ready to convert the attachment to a string and attach to the 'message' object

```
with open(attachment_path, 'rb') as ap:
message.add_attachment(ap.read(), maintype=mime_type, subtype=mime_subtype, filename=attachment_filename)
```

let's get to sending email:

```
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", port=587) as smtp:
  #smtp.set_debuglevel(1) #uncomment this statement to get processing information(run in debug mode)
  smtp.starttls()
  mail_pass=getpass.getpass('Password? ') #uncomment this statement to enter password at time of execution of script
  #default prompt is 'password' for getpass method
  smtp.login(message['From'], mail_pass) #NOTE:here password is in plain context
  #To use password in more secure way, use getpass module
  smtp.send_message(message)
```

To know if your message sent successfully, let's add

```
print('message sent successfully from {} to {}'.format(message['From'], message['To']))
```